# css селектор. js. как добавить переменные внутрь css селектора?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

нужно перебрать элементы в сетке. Не получается правильно поместить переменные в css селектор. обратные кавычки не помогли. Приведите пожалста пример, как правильно это сделать. вот так не работает

`` element(by.css(".mainGrid .row:nth-child(`${i+1}`) .icon:nth-child(`${j+1}`)")) ``

Answer (score 0):

Обратные кавычки не должны быть внутри обычных. Попробуйте так:

```
element(by.css(`.mainGrid .row:nth-child(${i+1}) .icon:nth-child(${j+1})`))
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, все запалило!